# How to make a library for Android and make it available to use as a dependency?

Tags: android, sdk

I want to make a library so that other apps can integrate into their application. How do I make it?

Comment: SDK? do you know the definition of SDK?  isn't a library enough?

Comment: Sorry, we do not know what you are trying to point out.

Comment: Its just that Facebook has its own facebookSDK for integration in our apps if we want to .. How to achieve make such type of SDK ..

Comment: @bhaskar the SDK on the FacebookSDK is just a part of the title that they call it. it's actually just another library built for the benefit of users who have interactions with Facebook on their apps.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new Android Project and then inside that project create a new Android Library Module.

`File -> New -> Module -> Android Library`

Then give it a name. e.g. `mylib`

Use the `app` module for library usage examples i.e. show people integrating your library how to use it.

Then put all the source you need for your library into the `mylib` module you created.

As for distribution, there are different ways to distribute the library. This post is a good place to start.

It goes through the steps you need to follow to distribute it using `jcenter` and `mavenCentral`.

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en

Comment: thank you .. i will try this one out.. i hope this helps me :)